# Convert Foreach Loop into Linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

Folks, I want to convert these loops into simple loop.
I saw answers related to linq but couldn't make out from that. IS there any other possible ways for this snippet?

```
XmlDocument manifestXmlFile = new XmlDocument();
manifestXmlFile.Load(manifestFileName);

foreach (XmlNode rules in manifestXmlFile.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
{
    foreach (XmlNode ruleNode in rules)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode childNodeAttributes in ruleNode)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode childNodeAttrib in childNodeAttributes.ChildNodes)
            {
                XmlElement ruleElement = (XmlElement)ruleNode;
                foreach (XmlNode childNodeConditions in childNodeAttrib.ChildNodes)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode childNodeCond in childNodeConditions.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        if (childNodeCond.Name.ToUpper() == "CONDITION")
                        {
                            if (childNodeCond.Attributes["type"].Value.ToUpper() == "HEALTHY")
                            {
                                string ruleId = ruleElement.Attributes["ruleid"].Value;
                                string attributeName = childNodeAttrib.Attributes["name"].Value;
                                string attributeType = childNodeAttrib.Attributes["type"].Value;
                                string condTypeValue = childNodeCond.Attributes["type"].Value;
                                string operatorValue = childNodeCond.Attributes["operator"].Value;
                                string healthyConditionValue = childNodeCond.FirstChild.InnerText;

                                var guid = new Guid(ruleId);

                                //Conversion of enum types
                                PsmsOperator psmsOperator = (PsmsOperator)Enum.Parse(typeof(PsmsOperator), operatorValue, true);
                                TypeCode psmsAttributeType = (TypeCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(TypeCode), attributeType, true);

                                Rule rule = new Rule(guid, attributeName, healthyConditionValue, psmsOperator);

                                Rule(attributes, guid);
                           }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any other better way than this or linq?

Comment: `simple loop` from 6 nested foreach loops? No way :)

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is right place to ask this question

Comment: use XPath. it's the proper (and likely most efficient way) to get this down to a simple loop

Comment: I suggest you use XPath instead of those loops. For more information about XPath, look at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp).

Answer (score 4):

Use XPath to select the node you want.

```
foreach (var node in manifestXmlFile.SelectNodes(@"//condition[@type = 'healthy']")
{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.. It can be done just because you can, but its ugly :)
(Credits goes to R#):

```
foreach (Rule rule in from XmlNode rules in manifestXmlFile.DocumentElement.ChildNodes 
                        from XmlNode ruleNode in rules 
                        from XmlNode childNodeAttributes in ruleNode 
                        from XmlNode childNodeAttrib in childNodeAttributes.ChildNodes 
                        let ruleElement = (XmlElement) ruleNode 
                        from XmlNode childNodeConditions in childNodeAttrib.ChildNodes 
                        from XmlNode childNodeCond in childNodeConditions.ChildNodes
                        where childNodeCond.Name.ToUpper() == "CONDITION" 
                        where childNodeCond.Attributes["type"].Value.ToUpper() == "HEALTHY" 
                        let ruleId = ruleElement.Attributes["ruleid"].Value 
                        let attributeName = childNodeAttrib.Attributes["name"].Value 
                        let attributeType = childNodeAttrib.Attributes["type"].Value 
                        let condTypeValue = childNodeCond.Attributes["type"].Value 
                        let operatorValue = childNodeCond.Attributes["operator"].Value 
                        let healthyConditionValue = childNodeCond.FirstChild.InnerText 
                        let guid = new Guid(ruleId) 
                        let psmsOperator = (PsmsOperator) Enum.Parse(typeof (PsmsOperator), operatorValue, true) 
                        let psmsAttributeType = (TypeCode) Enum.Parse(typeof (TypeCode), attributeType, true) 
                        select new Rule(guid, attributeName, healthyConditionValue, psmsOperator))
{
    //do something with rule varialbe
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will do the trick

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(manifestFileName);
root.Element("RootElement").Elements("rules").Elements("ruleNode").Elements("CONDITION").All<XElement>(xe =>
{
    if(xe.Attribute("type").Value.ToUpper() == "HEALTHY")
    {
        //do
    }
}
```